# Ubuntu install Windows using a partition on the hard drive

Tags: system-installation, boot-partition

How to partition the hard drive to install Ubuntu.

On the laptop is currently installed windows and I would like to keep it.

Thank you!

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? Which is gpt partitioning if UEFI or MBR(msdos) if Windows is booting in BIOS mode. Just be sure to install Ubuntu in same boot mode. And how you boot install media, is then how it installs.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: Sorry. You're right. I'll be more consistent next time! Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the response to @oldfred question. Believe it or not your question is quite likely a duplicate - UEFI - http://askubuntu.com/search?q=dual+boot+uefi or BIOS - http://askubuntu.com/search?q=dual+boot+bios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shrink/resize your Win partition to make space for Ubuntu partition and then create one.

Go for classic **LTS desktop** Ubuntu version. LTS for less bugs. Desktop, now its personal.

During install you should choose "soomething else" option, if you want to have control of your Windows partition.